# Gradle: Including an object .o file while building a static library

Tags: gradle, native

I'm trying to build a native cpp project with gradle which links against an external .o object file.
Lets call it externalDep.o

---

What would be the correct gradle syntax so that this object file gets included when I build my static library?

Current my code looks like this
myProj
\
cpp\ headers\ objectFile\
with the headers and cpp for my project with externalDep.o in the objectFile dir since gradle only looks for .cpp and .hpp in cpp and headers

---

After the cppCompiler args,

```
libraries {
    mylib {
        binaries.all {
            linker.args "path_to_externalDep.o"
        }
    }
}
```

but it does not include this .o file while building the static library

(I'm looking for the equivalent of

```
Make library source_file(i-k).o externalDep.o
```

)
 Thanks

Comment: I'll add here that I also tried staticLibArchiver.args "path_to_externalDep.o" but this included my file but did an "ar" on it. Since this is not .a file but a .o file this was wrong.

Comment: Did you verify that path_to_externalDep is correct and the file exists?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! yes, I did confirm and I was able to figure it out eventually. I had the object file which was external initially in the src dir. My mistake was trying to set a linker argument to link it. In the end all I had to do was copy the object file over using a copy task to my cbkbuild/obj/..lib/projectCpp folder and it automatically got picked up and linked as a part of  ar rcs lib.a objectfiles.o

Comment: Why is this a mistake? This should generally be possible...

Comment: I guessed so as well but I ended up spending a lot of time on it using args from the gradle 2.2 docs and couldn't make headway. A simple copy task to move the object file over into cbkbuild/obj.. seems to work for now. Thanks a lot for looking into this!

Comment: Cool. Just one more thing - note that in Gradle 2.3. the DSL for building Native binaries was changed so your current code will need some modifications (you can read more about it in [Gradle 2.3 Release Notes](http://gradle.org/docs/current/release-notes#gradle-no-long-builds-native-binaries-for-all-defined-platforms) and in the [Building Native Binaries documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the object file which was external initially in the src dir.

My mistake was trying to set a linker argument to link it.

In the end all I had to do was copy the object file over using a copy task to my cbkbuild/obj/..StaticLibrary/projectCpp folder and it automatically got picked up and linked as a part of ar rcs lib.a objectfiles.o